# How can I find the GC-content of a FASTA file using a Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, bioinformatics, fasta, dna-sequence

I want to find the [GC-content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GC-content) from a [FASTA format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) format file using a Bash script.
The GC-content is basically *(number of ([G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanine) + [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytosine))) / (number of ([A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenine) + [T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thymine) + G + C))*.

I am trying to use the [wc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc) command. But I was not able to get an answer.

---

After going through documentation and videos, I came up with a solution.

```
filename=$@                     # Collecting all the filenames as parameters
for f in $filename              # Looping over files
do
    echo " $f is being processed..."
    gc=( $( grep -v ">" < "$f" | grep -io 'g\|c'< "$f" | wc -l))    # Reading lines that don’t start with < using -v. grep -io matches to either g or c and outputs each match on single line. wc -l counts the number of lines or indirectly the number of g and c. This is stored in a variable.
    total=( $( grep -v ">" < "$f" | tr -d '\s\r' | wc -c))          # Spaces, tabs, new line are removed from the file using tr. Then the number of characters are counted by wc -c
    percent=( $( echo "scale=2;100*$gc/$total" |bc -l))             # bc -l is used to get the answer in float format. scale=2 mentions the number of decimal points.
    echo " The GC content of $f is: "$percent"%"
    echo
done
```

I am learning bioinformatics.

Comment: Why `wc`? Wouldn't `grep`, `awk`,  or a real programming language be the better tool for the job? Can you [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi @Robert, I am just starting out with linux and bash. At that I wasn't aware of grep, awk. But you are right, these tools are better suited to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do not reinvent the wheel. For common bioinformatics tasks, use open-source tools that are specifically designed for these tasks, are well-tested, widely used, and handle edge cases. For example, use [`EMBOSS`](https://emboss.sourceforge.net/) `infoseq` utility. `EMBOSS` can be easily installed, for example using [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html).

Example:

Install `EMBOSS` package (do once):

```
conda create --name emboss emboss --channel iuc
```

Activate the `conda` environment and use `EMBOSS` `infoseq`, here to print the sequence name, length and percent GC:

```
source activate emboss

cat your_sequence_file_name.fasta | infoseq -auto -only -name -length -pgc stdin

source deactivate
```

This prints into [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) something like this:

```
Name           Length %GC
seq_foo        119    60.50
seq_bar        104    39.42
seq_baz        191    46.60
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I appreciate it. But in no way I was trying to reinvent the wheel. This question was in response to a task given to me at a place I am interning. I was struggling with this for long, so I thought of taking help from community.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# Adapted from https://www.biostars.org/p/17680

# Fail on error
set -o errexit
# Disable undefined variable reference
set -o nounset

# ================
# CONFIGURATION
# ================
# Fasta file path
FASTA_FILE="file.fasta"
# Number of digits after decimal point
N_DIGITS=3

# ================
# LOGGER
# ================
# Fatal log message
fatal() {
  printf '[FATAL] %s\n' "$@" >&2
  exit 1
}

# Info log message
info() {
  printf '[INFO ] %s\n' "$@"
}

# ================
# MAIN
# ================
{
  # Check command 'bc' exist
  command -v bc > /dev/null 2>&1 || fatal "Command 'bc' not found"
  # Check file exist
  [ -f "$FASTA_FILE" ] || fatal "File '$FASTA_FILE' not found"

  # Count number of sequences
  _n_sequences=$(grep --count '^>' "$FASTA_FILE")
  info "Analyzing $_n_sequences sequences"
  [ "$_n_sequences" -ne 0 ] || fatal "No sequences found"

  # Remove sequence wrapping
  _fasta_file_content=$(
    sed 's/\(^>.*$\)/#\1#/' "$FASTA_FILE" \
      | tr --delete "\r\n" \
      | sed 's/$/#/' \
      | tr "#" "\n" \
      | sed '/^$/d'
  )

  # Vars
  _sequence=
  _a_count_total=0
  _c_count_total=0
  _g_count_total=0
  _t_count_total=0

  # Read line by line
  while IFS= read -r _line; do
    # Check if header
    if printf '%s\n' "$_line" | grep --quiet '^>'; then
      # Save sequence and continue
      _sequence=${_line#?}
      continue
    fi

    # Count
    _a_count=$(printf '%s\n' "$_line" | tr --delete --complement 'A' | wc --bytes)
    _c_count=$(printf '%s\n' "$_line" | tr --delete --complement 'C' | wc --bytes)
    _g_count=$(printf '%s\n' "$_line" | tr --delete --complement 'G' | wc --bytes)
    _t_count=$(printf '%s\n' "$_line" | tr --delete --complement 'T' | wc --bytes)

    # Add current count to total
    _a_count_total=$((_a_count_total + _a_count))
    _c_count_total=$((_c_count_total + _c_count))
    _g_count_total=$((_g_count_total + _g_count))
    _t_count_total=$((_t_count_total + _t_count))

    # Calculate GC content
    _gc=$(
      printf 'scale = %d; a = %d; c = %d; g = %d; t = %d; (g + c) / (a + c + g + t)\n' \
        "$N_DIGITS" "$_a_count" "$_c_count" "$_g_count" "$_t_count" \
        | bc
    )
    # Add 0 before decimal point
    _gc="$(printf "%.${N_DIGITS}f\n" "$_gc")"

    info "Sequence '$_sequence' GC content: $_gc"
  done << EOF
$_fasta_file_content
EOF

  # Total data
  info "Adenine total count: $_a_count_total"
  info "Cytosine total count: $_c_count_total"
  info "Guanine total count: $_g_count_total"
  info "Thymine total count: $_t_count_total"

  # Calculate total GC content
  _gc=$(
    printf 'scale = %d; a = %d; c = %d; g = %d; t = %d; (g + c) / (a + c + g + t)\n' \
      "$N_DIGITS" "$_a_count_total" "$_c_count_total" "$_g_count_total" "$_t_count_total" \
      | bc
  )
  # Add 0 before decimal point
  _gc="$(printf "%.${N_DIGITS}f\n" "$_gc")"
  info "GC content: $_gc"
}
```

The "*Count number of sequences*" and "*Remove sequence wrapping*" codes are adapted from https://www.biostars.org/p/17680

The script uses only basic commands except for [bc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc) to do the precision calculation (See [bc installation](https://command-not-found.com/bc)).

You can configure the script by modifying the variables in the `CONFIGURATION` section.

Because you haven't indicated which one you want, the GC content is calculated for both each sequence and the overall. Therefore, get rid of anything that isn't necessary :)

Despite my lack of bioinformatics background, the script successfully parses and analyzes a fasta file.

Comment: Thank you. I am just starting out with bash and bioinformatics. This will help me.